# Jenkins Blue Ocean ./gradlew: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am having trouble getting Blue Ocean to recognize where my default gradle folder is on my Mac OSX. I have **GRADLE_HOME** set to **/opt/gradle**.

I keep getting the following error message when running my shell script `./gradlew assembleDebug`:

> /Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/project@tmp/durable-d97717dc/script.sh:
>   line 2: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
>
> script returned exit code 1

[image: pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

I could see two reasons for that error:

1. Your script is not executed in the folder where your `gradlew` lays.
2. The `gradlew` has not set the correct permissions set for the calling user.

Adding a check for existing and the correct permissions on the file to execute could help you to sort these problems out.